# How to control the background color of a square of a panel on wxPython?

Tags: wxpython

So I'm writing a code from scratch, and I am down to the part of placing a static text (nonchanging) with a grey background. I can change the font with `.ForegroundColour` but not with `BackgroundColour`

Here's the code

```
s_text2 = wx.StaticText(self.panel1, -1, "\n\n\nStop\n\n\n", (x1size+30,10)) 
s_text2.SetBackgroundColour('grey')
```

Any thoughts?

Yeah, here is a short to the point sample

```
import wx

class Prototype(wx.Frame):
     def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, size=(550,300))

        self.InitUI()
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()
    #define User Interface
    def InitUI(self):
        self.panel1 = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer() #Main window sizer
        self.sizer.Add(self.panel1, 1, flag=wx.EXPAND)

        self.hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.panel1.SetSizer(self.hbox)

        #Static Text
        s_text1 = wx.StaticText(self.panel1, -1, "Hello World!", (10,5)) #top text
        self.s_text2 = wx.StaticText(self.panel1, -1, "\n\n\nStop\n\n\n", (300,10)) #top text
        self.s_text2.SetBackgroundColour("blue")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    Prototype(None, title='')
    app.MainLoop()
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved it, thx anyways guys for trying

```
import wx

class Prototype(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, size=(550,300))

        self.InitUI()
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()
    #define User Interface
    def InitUI(self):
        self.panel1 = wx.Panel(self, -1)

        #Static Text
        s_text1 = wx.StaticText(self.panel1, -1, "Hello World!", (10,5)) #top text
        self.s_text2 = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel1, style=wx.TE_READONLY | wx.NO_BORDER, pos=(300,10)) #top text
        self.s_text2.AppendText("gray")
        self.s_text2.SetBackgroundColour("gray")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    Prototype(None, title='')
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
import wx

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.text = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label="Test")
        self.text.SetBackgroundColour("gray")
        self.text.SetForegroundColour(wx.WHITE)

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        self.sizer.Add(self.text)

        self.panel.SetSizerAndFit(self.sizer)  
        self.Show()

app = wx.App(False)
win = MainWindow(None)
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: That example individually works, but not with my code


Is it ncessary to `BoxSizer()` and `.Add()`? im trying to position it by giving it coordinates

Comment: Can you create a small runnable example which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I do not see anything wrong in your code and the background is blue on my system. Windows 7, wxPython 2.8.12.1, Python 2.7.3.

Comment: Try removing all the sizers. You do not use them anyway.

Comment: That didn't solve it
I'm using python 2.6.6, you think upgrading it would do the trick?

Comment: What is your OS and wxPython version?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the wxGTK port then static texts may not be able to have background colors because they are not a true widget.  Instead they are just drawn directly on the parent and the active theme can have some influence over whether the background color will be used or not.

There is a generic class in wx.lib.stattext that is a true widget and so you can use it instead.

Comment: So is wx.StaticText a part of wxGTK?

Comment: The class is there, but like I said the native widget used will not be  a true widget with its own native window, etc.